# How data is split into part files in sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop-partitioning

I've a doubt how the data is partitioned into part files if the data is skewed. If possible, please help me clarifying this.

Let's say this my `department` table with `department_id` as primary key.

```
mysql> select * from departments;
2 Fitness
3 Footwear
4 Apparel
5 Golf
6 Outdoors
7 Fan Shop
```

If I use `sqoop import` by mentioning `-m 1` in the import command, I know I will have only one part file generated with all the records in that.

Now I ran the command without specifying any mappers. So by default it should take 4 mappers and it created 4 part files in HDFS. Below is how the records got distributed per part file.

```
[cloudera@centsosdemo ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/departments/part-m-00000
2,Fitness
3,Footwear
[cloudera@centsosdemo ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/departments/part-m-00001
4,Apparel
[cloudera@centsosdemo ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/departments/part-m-00002
5,Golf
[cloudera@centsosdemo ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/departments/part-m-00003
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop
```

As per the BoundingValsQuery, Min(department_id)=2, Max(department_id)=8 and 4 mappers are to be used by default.

Upon calculation, each mapper should get (8-2)/4=1.5 records.

Here I'm not getting how to distribute the data. I couldn't understand how 2 records came in part-m-00000 and only one in part-m-00001, part-m-00002 and again two in part-m-00003.

Comment: you should explain better want you want if you want someone to help you. You should at least explain  what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to know how data is split among the part files i.e. which record is going to which part file.

Comment: Sqoop creates sql query for each mapper. You can check the SQL from all Workers Node.Can you Run all sql query on your sql server and share the result?

Comment: @SandeepSingh Firstly I'm using mysql. Basically I'm aware that sqoop creates sql query for each mapper. But I wanted to know like how the query is prepared and how the outliers for each mapper are decided.

Comment: @ElmerDantas- Actually I wanted to see how query are getting formed in your case, since maximum value in data is 7 but you have assigned 8

Answer (score 0):

If you get a chance to look into library. There are sequence of steps involved in it.

> Sqoop job Read records. via DBRecordReader

```
 org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader
```

Two methods will do work here.

method 1.

```
protected ResultSet executeQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
Integer fetchSize = dbConf.getFetchSize();
/*get fetchSize according to split which is calculated via getSplits() method of 
org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.And no. of splits are calculated
via no. of (count from table/no. of mappers). */
 }
```

Split Calculation:-

```
org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat
 public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext job) throws IOException {
 .......//here splits are calculated accroding to count of source table
 .......query.append("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName);
}
```

method 2.

```
 protected String getSelectQuery() {
    if (dbConf.getInputQuery() == null) {
      query.append("SELECT ");

      for (int i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        query.append(fieldNames[i]);
        if (i != fieldNames.length -1) {
          query.append(", ");
        }
      }

      query.append(" FROM ").append(tableName);
      query.append(" AS ").append(tableName); 
      if (conditions != null && conditions.length() > 0) {
        query.append(" WHERE (").append(conditions).append(")");
      }

      String orderBy = dbConf.getInputOrderBy();
      if (orderBy != null && orderBy.length() > 0) {
        query.append(" ORDER BY ").append(orderBy);
      }
    } else {
      //PREBUILT QUERY
      query.append(dbConf.getInputQuery());
    }

    try {// main logic to decide division of records between mappers.
      query.append(" LIMIT ").append(split.getLength());
      query.append(" OFFSET ").append(split.getStart());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      // Ignore, will not throw.
    }

    return query.toString();
  }
```

check out for code section under comments **main logic to.......**
Here records are divided according to LIMIT and OFFSET. And this logic is implemented differently for every RDBMS. just look for `org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.OracleDBRecordReader` it has little different implementation of getSelectQuery() method.

Hope this gives quick idea about how records are divided into different mappers.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop finds the min and max value in the primary key column or the split by column and then tries to divide the range for the given number of mappers.

**Example**, if you had a table with a primary key column of id whose minimum value was 0 and maximum value was 1000, and Sqoop was directed to use 4 tasks, Sqoop would run four processes which each execute SQL statements of the form SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id >= lo AND id < hi, with (lo, hi) set to (0, 250), (250, 500), (500, 750), and (750, 1001) in the different tasks.

Here min val =2 max=7 hence sqoop will run four processes with following ranges ( 2-4) , (4-5) , (5-6),(6-7) which means

1. 2nd and 3rd together
2. 4th record
3. 5th record
4. 6th and 7th in this range